# Does SQL Server Management Studio 2017 Contain a New Explain Feature

Tags: sql-server, ssms, explain

## TL;DR

I happened upon a feature in SQL Server Management Studio v17.9 which I was not aware of. It looks a bit like the `EXPLAIN` found in Oracle, PostgreSQL and MySQL. Where is this feature documented?

## How to Turn The Feature On

I was running the following query with the options **Include Actual Execution Plan (Ctrl + M)** and **Include Live Query Statistics** turned on:

```
    SELECT sdes.session_id
          ,sdes.[status]
          ,sdes.login_name
          ,sdes.[host_name]
          ,sder.blocking_session_id
          ,sdb.name
          ,sdes.cpu_time
          ,sdes.logical_reads --optionally: + sdes.reads + sdes.writes
          ,sdes.last_request_start_time
          ,sdes.program_name
          ,sdes.session_id
          ,sder.request_id
          ,dest.[text]
    FROM   sys.dm_exec_sessions             AS sdes
           LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections     AS sdec
                ON  sdes.session_id = sdec.session_id
           JOIN sys.databases               AS sdb
                ON  sdes.database_id = sdb.database_id
           LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests  AS sder
                ON  sdes.session_id = sder.session_id
           CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sdec.most_recent_sql_handle) AS dest
    WHERE 1=1
    AND sdb.name = ''
```

### Outcome

This produced four results tabs:

- Results
- Messages
- Live Query Statistics
- Execution Plan

### Special Results Tab

When I switched to the **Results** tab, I noticed a result set just below the actual results which looks like this:

[image: SQL Server Management Studio - Explain Plan]

---

## Observations

If I turn on either the **Include Actual Execution Plan (Ctrl + M)** option or the **Include Live Query Statistics** option, then the **SQL Server Explain** isn't displayed. The "SQL Server Explain" is only displayed if both options are turned on.

---

## Questions

1. Can this feature be turned on without having to activate both **Include Actual Execution Plan (Ctrl + M)** option and the **Include Live Query Statistics**?
2. Where is this neat little feature documented?

---

## Prerequisites

The following components and/or software packages are involved in the scenario:

### Server

- Windows Server 2016
- SQL Server 2016 SP1

### Client

- Windows 10 Version 1807 (Build 17134)
- SQL Server Management Studio v17.9

  - Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio    14.0.17285.0
  - Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools  14.0.1016.283
  - Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)   10.0.17134.1
  - Microsoft MSXML                           3.0 6.0
  - Microsoft Internet Explorer               9.11.17134.0
  - Microsoft .NET Framework                  4.0.30319.42000
  - Operating System                          6.3.17134

### SQL Server Management Studio v17.9

- **Include Actual Execution Plan (Ctrl + M)** turned **ON**
- **Include Live Query Statistics** turned **ON**

Comment: i am reporting the same on 17.4, this seems to be around on earlier versions of ssms https://ibb.co/ZMP35fF

Comment: It's also in 2016

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, not a feature - it's turning one of these on:

```
SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON;  
SET STATISTICS PROFILE ON;
```

[The SHOWPLAN_TEXT option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-showplan-text-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [STATISTICS PROFILE option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statistics-profile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) are well-documented and have been around for over a decade, but I don't know when SSMS started turning it on for the combo of live query plans and actual plans. I would consider it a bug.

[Here's the SSMS bug I filed for it.](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/35425927-ssms-bug-set-statistics-profile-on-is-enabled-whe)